# mocking the default middleware function in koa-jwt using jest

Tags: jwt, koa

I am using `koa-jwt` which in turn uses `jsonwebtoken`. Here's my router implementation:

`index.ts`

```
const jwt = require('koa-jwt');
...
// some other code
...

export const publicEndpoints = ['/', '/openapi.json', '/healthcheck'];

export default new Router<ApplicationState, ApplicationContext>()
  .use(configure)
  .use((ctx,next) => {
    console.log("REACH 02 opts",ctx,next);
    console.log("REACH 02 jwt", jwt);
  })
  .use(
    jwt({
      secret: customSecretLoader,
      audience: (jwksConfig.audience as unknown) as string,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    }).unless({ path: publicEndpoints })
  )
  // Public endpoints
  .use('/openapi.json', swagger)
  .use('/', helloworld)
  .use('/healthcheck', healthcheck)

  // Secure endpoints
  .get('/secure', helloworld)
  .middleware();
```

calling `/secure` should pass through the middleware that calls `jwt` and passes the token

I want to test every secure route to make sure that it does not pass any requests that don't have the right token and passes the ones that do.

The prior was easy, I just needed to call a secure route:

`index.test.ts`

```
  it('Unauthenticated secure request returns 401', async () => {
    const response = await request(server).get('/secure');
    expect(response.status).toEqual(401);
  });
```

The latter however, to get it working I need to mock the `jwt()` function call and have it return `200` but the **problem** is that regardless of what I write in my test I am still calling the original implementation of `koa-jwt`.

*To have some context, this is the `koa-js` library that I am trying to mock https://github.com/koajs/jwt/blob/master/lib/index.js. It returns `middleware()` which calls `verify` which in turn is using `jsonwebtoken` 
[image]
[image]

**Mocking the entire exported function**

`index.test.ts`

```
`var jwt = require('koa-jwt');`

...
// some code
...

  it('Authenticated secure request returns 200', async () => {

    jwt = jest.fn(() => {
      Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        success: 'Token is valid'
      });
    });

    console.log("REACH 01 jwt", jwt);

    const response = await request(server).get('/secure');
    console.log("REACH RESPONSE",response);
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  });
```

The output I get from that in the console log is:

```
REACH 01 jwt function mockConstructor() {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
```

which is what I expect but when the `jwt()` is hit in `index.ts` the output I get is:

```
    REACH 02 jwt (opts = {}) => {
        const { debug, getToken, isRevoked, key = 'user', passthrough, tokenKey } = opts;
        const tokenResolvers = [resolveCookies, resolveAuthHeader];

        if (getToken && typeof getToken === 'function') {
            tokenResolvers.unshift(getToken);
        }

        const middleware = async function jwt(ctx, next) {
            let token;
            tokenResolvers.find(resolver => token = resolver(ctx, opts));
.....
```

I expect that having mocked `koa-jwt` that I would see the same output in both console logs.

I tried a few different things that gave me the same result:
- mocking the middleware function in the exported default function in `koa-js`
- mocking the dependency of `koa-js` which is `jsonwebtoken`

What am I missing?

Comment: For readability, I suggest you mention `js` in your code snippets as the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was mocking the entire module **outside** of the test:

```
import....

// some other code

jest.mock('koa-jwt', () => {
  const fn = jest.fn((opts) => // 1st level i.e. jwt()
  {
    const middlewareMock = jest.fn(async (ctx, next) => { // 2nd level i.e. middleware() 
      // Unreachable
    });
    // @ts-ignore
    middlewareMock.unless = jest.fn(() => jest.fn((ctx, next) => {
      next();
    })); // 4th level i.e. middleware().unless()
    return middlewareMock;
  });
  return fn;
});

... 

describe('routes: index', () => {
  // Testing each secure endpoint with authentication
  it('Authenticated requests to secure endpoints return 200', async () => {
    secureEndpoints.forEach(async (endpoint) => {
      const response = await request(server).get(endpoint);
      expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    });
  });
});
```